# Spring keeps returning String as Response instead of Html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am neither using `ResponseBody` nor I am using `RestController` annotation Still my Spring Application is returning String instead of jsp/html pages.

Here are my files of Application Configuration and Controller.
Where am I going wrong?

The GIT [link](https://github.com/gauravmatta/springmvc/tree/master/JavaBaseClassBootstrap) to my code

Web Configuration File:

```java
package com.springimplant.mvc.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver;

@Configuration  
@EnableWebMvc  
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.springimplant.mvc.controllers")  
public class SimpleWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
//      UrlBasedViewResolver bean = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver resourceBundleViewResolver() {
        ResourceBundleViewResolver bean = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
        bean.setBasename("views");
        bean.setOrder(1);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver xmlViewResolver(){
        XmlViewResolver bean = new XmlViewResolver();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("views.xml"));
        bean.setOrder(2);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
//      registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/welcome");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


}
```

HomeController:

```
package com.springimplant.mvc.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="welcome",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome Home
</body>
</html>
```

So I Had these page tag over my jsp file which I removed and now it runs fine but why?
I didn't had to do this for my earlier projects.

Comment: But why its working fine this way in my Other projects I didn't had requirement of doing this?